# Appium related：Failed to load global package 'opencv4nodejs': The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Tags: npm, appium-ios

Upload image gives opencv4nodjs error When did Appium UI automation test on Mac. opencv4nodejs installed actually. Does anyone encounter these issues, pls share your solution, thanks~

```
App Version: 1.17.1-1
Electron: 7.2.4
Node.js: 12.8.1
npm:6.14.5
```

Much more details as below（got from appium server

```
[Support] Linking package 'opencv4nodejs'
[Support] Unable to load package 'opencv4nodejs', linking failed: Command 'npm link opencv4nodejs' exited with code 226
[Support] npm ERR! code EROFS
[Support] npm ERR! syscall mkdir
[Support] npm ERR! path /node_modules
[Support] npm ERR! errno -30
[Support] npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/node_modules'
[Support] npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
[Support] npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.
[Support]
[Support] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[Support] npm ERR! /Users/winkynan/.npm/_logs/2020-08-18T10_36_04_164Z-debug.log
[Support]
[Support] Unable to load package 'opencv4nodejs': Unable to load package 'opencv4nodejs', linking failed: Command 'npm link opencv4nodejs' exited with code 226
[Support] Unable to load 'opencv4nodejs': Unable to load package 'opencv4nodejs': Unable to load package 'opencv4nodejs', linking failed: Command 'npm link opencv4nodejs' exited with code 226
[W3C (e35141ff)] Encountered internal error running command: Error: 'opencv4nodejs' module is required to use OpenCV features. Please install it first ('npm i -g opencv4nodejs') and restart Appium. Read https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs#how-to-install for more details on this topic.
```

Comment: reinstall  opencv4nodejs for several times，still not working

Comment: did you follow this steps https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs#macosx ?